# Python - I'm making a hangman game, and nothing gets updated

Tags: python

So pretty much it's in the title.
Once you type a letter in it returns the same thing from the beginning. I'm new to python and I don't know that much about it, I've tried finding a solution to it here already but was unsuccesful. I don't think it's very complicated so I hope someone can figure out what is wrong.

```
import random

HANGMAN = (
    """

------
|    |
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
----------
""",
    """

------
|    |
|    O
|
|
|
|
|
|
----------
""",
    """

------
|    |
|    O
|   -+-
|
|
|
|
|
----------
""",
    """


------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-
|
|
|
|
|
----------
""",
    """

------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|
|
|
|
|
----------
""",
    """

------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|    |
|
|
|
|
----------
""",
    """

------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|    |
|    |
|   |
|   |  
|
----------
""",
    """

------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|    |
|    |
|   | |
|   | |
|
----------
""")

MAX_WRONG = len(HANGMAN) - 1

WORDS = ("WAREHOUSE", "HINGE", "SPOON", "WALLET", "GRATE", "POCKET", "REINDEER", "NILE", "POISON", "LEGEND", "SAXOPHONE",
"CIRCUS", "SILO", "FLOOD", "DISH", "SCANDAL", "FRAME", "CAFE")

word = random.choice(WORDS)  

guessed = "-" * len(slowo)

wrong = 0

used = []

print("Welcome to Hangman!'.\n WARNING! Type all the letters in uppercase")

while wrong < MAX_WRONG and guessed != word:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])  
    print("\nYou used these letters already:\n", used)
    print("\nYou guessed these many so far:\n", guessed)

    guess = input("\n\nType in a letter: ")
    guess = guess.upper()

    while guess in used:  
        print("You've already used: ", guess)
        guess = input("Wprowadź literę: ")
        guess = guess.upper()

used.append(guess)

if guess in word:
    print("\nGood Job!", guess, "is in the hidden word!")

    new = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            new += guess
        else:
            new += guessed[i]
    guessed = new

else:
    print("\nLetter: ", guess, "isn't featured in the hidden word.")
    wrong += 1

if wrong == MAX_WRONG:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou died...")
else:
    print("\nCongratulations! You guessed the hidden word!")

print("\The hidden word was: ", word)

input('\n\nTo end the process, press ENTER.')
```

### That's it, if you've run the code you may've seen that it just returns

### |    |
|
|
|
|
|
|
|

You used these letters already:
[]

### You guessed these many so far:

Comment: Please, at least translate your code to English.

Comment: @AlanWik I can understand all of it and it's still a nightmare to read because of language mix.

Comment: @AlanWik lmao hadn't noticed the language until you mentioned, too pain to read

Comment: You never update your guesses in the first `while` loop

Comment: Updated it to english

Answer (score 0):

I had to learn a little bit of Polish to walk through what was happening, but it looks like this section of code needs to be indented so that it is in the first `while` block:

```
uzyte.append(traf)

if traf in slowo:
    print("\nBrawo!", traf, "znajduje się w ukrytym słowie!")

    nowy = ""
    for i in range(len(slowo)):
        if traf == slowo[i]:
            nowy += traf
        else:
            nowy += odgadniete[i]
    odgadniete = nowy

else:
    print("\nLitera: ", traf, "nie występuje w ukrytym słowie.")
    zle += 1

if zle == MAX_ZLE:
    print(WISIELEC[zle])
    print("\nNie żyjesz...")
else:
    print("\nGratulacje! Odgadłeś ukryte słowo!")
```

Result:

```
Wykorzystałeś już następujące litery:
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

Na razie odgadłeś tyle liter:
 --A-A


Wprowadź literę: h

Litera:  H nie występuje w ukrytym słowie.

------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|    |
|    |
|   | |
|   | |
|
----------


Nie żyjesz...
>>>
```

Here's a working example of the (now translated) while block:

```
while wrong < MAX_WRONG and guessed != word:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou used these letters already:\n", used)
    print("\nYou guessed these many so far:\n", guessed)

    guess = input("\n\nType in a letter: ")
    guess = guess.upper()

    while guess in used:
        print("You've already used: ", guess)
        guess = input("Wprowadź literę: ")
        guess = guess.upper()

    used.append(guess)

    if guess in word:
        print("\nGood Job!", guess, "is in the hidden word!")

        new = ""
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                new += guess
            else:
                new += guessed[i]
        guessed = new

    else:
        print("\nLetter: ", guess, "isn't featured in the hidden word.")
        wrong += 1

    if wrong == MAX_WRONG:
        print(HANGMAN[wrong])
        print("\nYou died...")
    else:
        print("\nCongratulations! You guessed the hidden word!")
```

Comment: Still returns nothing to me and without any errors :/